# In between of EditText how to use autocomplete android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I know how to use EditText in android and how to use AutoComplete EditText in android. But AutoComplete EditText is used like dropdown list where user type a character and suggestions will be displayed and user clicks on one of the suggestions. If there is no suggestion then it won't display any text.

My requirement is like, Consider there is an EditText. User can type anything they want, but when the word starts from special character like for example "@" then the api will hit and display suggestions.

Complete Example:

"My Name is James Bond and I am @And"

In above example when user type this sentence at the end "@And" it will show the auto suggestion from hitting the API(should display Android) and user can select this suggested word from list.

Is there any way to achieve this??

Please Do help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. Use this widget instead of EditText and override its tokenizer.

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView myautocomplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multy);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_for_autocomplete);
    myautocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    myautocomplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer() {
        @Override
        public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
                i--;
            }
            while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                i++;
            }

            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;
            int len = text.length();

            while (i < len) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == ',') {
                    return i;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return len;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
            int i = text.length();

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                i--;
            }

            if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ',') {
                return text;
            } else {
                if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + ", ");
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                            Object.class, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return text + ", ";
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: There is no method as setTokenizer() in AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` and override methods. It does have setTokenizer() method.

Comment: No, This is not the solution to my question

Comment: I have updated my answer, and this time i have tested it personally. It works perfectly. Complete working code.

Comment: This is actually good, Can I remove @ after selecting from suggestion??? Should have to display only selected suggestion.

Comment: Think logically, in those methods `terminateToken` would trigger when you select the suggested words, so you can implement your logic in there to remove '@' character.

Comment: But in that method, when i checked what data i am getting. It is the only selected text without @.

Comment: Then, you can do it on `findTokenStart` where it's checking when it hits the '@' character. you are getting text variable there too, so you can remove from that method.

Comment: Hello Ajay, I have another question. Is it possible like if there is no suggestion from adapter, then whatever the user typed then that should be displayed as suggestion. can we do this???